# Site Personalization : Font & Background

Tags: asp.net, fonts, coding-style, background, personalization

I have a website with a masterpage and a page called personalize.

I Want to change the background image of my site using a dropdownlist from that page.
My current background and font are defined in my body

Any idea on how to change my background and font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the Master page define (public?) a variable for the background image, and have it set a "default" value.

Give the Personalize page the dropdownlist, and in the OnChange event for that list, set the background image variable.

Comment: I got the second part, but how do I define an image variable and make it act at my background?